# Server side request error in NextJs | Laravel

Tags: laravel, next.js, axios

I'm using Laravel (as api) with Sanctum to Authentication and for client side NextJs 13 with App router.

I want to use in Next Static Site Generation so I want to call an laravel endpoit in a page like this:

```
import CategoryService from "services/CategoryService";
import { CategoryView } from "views/admin/category";
import { XSRF_TOKEN } from "utils/cookies/constants";
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export default async function Page() {

  const fds = cookies().get('final_draw_session')?.value;
  const xsrf = cookies().get(XSRF_TOKEN)?.value


  const response = await CategoryService.getAll(fds, xsrf);
  const categories = response.data.data;

  return (
    <CategoryView categories={categories} />
  )
}
```

and in the CategoryService I have:

```
class CategoryService {

  async getAll(fds, xsrf) {
   
    return await httpAPIClient.get('/categories', {
      headers: {
        'XSRF-TOKEN': xsrf,
        'final_draw_session': fds
      }
    })
  }

}

export default new CategoryService();
```

If I inspect the console we can see that the headers were set:

[image]

But I got an error

[image]

In postman this works

[image]

I need help to call some protected laravel endpoints in Server Side in NextJs because I also tried using axios interceptors to set the cookie but I can't get the client cookies in Server side

Comment: If you are getting a 500, just check the laravel logs, it will be there, or check the browser network tab for the response (content) so you can see the error